# Using multiple markers in Log4j 2 to filter logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to set up my log4j logger to use multiple `Marker`'s when filtering what to log. I'm not entirely sure if I'm even on the right track, but basically I want is to be able to log a number of different events based on a number of different markers.

Suppose I have three markers, `MARKERONE`, `MARKERTWO` and `MARKERTHREE`. These three are all "top-level" markers, meaning they cannot enherit from either of the other markers.

Currently I've got the following `log4j.xml` configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">

      <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERONE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERTWO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERTHREE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is based on the example xml-file from the log4j website: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter

This doesn't work, however, because of errors. I then tried replacing the three `MarkerFilter` entries with the following:

```
<Filters>
    <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERONE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERTWO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERTHREE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</Filters>
```

This allowed me to run the logging tool and actually log stuff, but (!) I am only able to log events logged with `MARKERONE`. If I change the order of the `MarkerFilter`'s, only events using the first `MarkerFilter` will be logged.

Ultimately my goal is to be able to specify exactly what I would like to log (in the xml-file for example), eg.: "I would like to log `MARKERTWO` and `MARKERTHREE`, but not `MARKERONE`".

I'm thinking there has to be a way for me to log whatever I want to log, without being limited to one `Marker`. Isn't this so? How do I log using multiple markers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the first two `onMismatch=NEUTRAL` and keep the last one as `onMismatch=DENY`. That way 2nd and 3rd aren't automatically denied after processing the first.